# Engine makes rattling sound when start and accelerate uphill?

Tags: engine, noise, peugeot

I have an 07 Peugeot 207 SE 120BHP 1.6L with 105,000km on it. When I start the car the engine makes a strange rattling sound when I accelerate up a hill. This is especially true in a higher gear. Weather temperature doesn't seem to affect. Any thoughts on the cause?

Comment: Have you noticed that the rattle is louder at a specific engine speed (RPM), or is it constant throughout the range?

Comment: I had one once that would rattle along with how I pushed on the throttle. Throttled a little and I got a little rattle, throttled heavy and the rattling was worst. Turned out one of the cooling fans had broken loose and (I assume) the force from throttling determined how far it would lean into the fan housing casing the blades to hit lightly or harder. Doubt this is your problem but figured I'd throw it out there just to remind people its not always things you would first assume.

Comment: Sounds like engine ping due to low octane gas or too much initial ignition timing.

Comment: I have noticed this at lower RPMs so I need to accelerate to higher RPMs to stop it happening, it gradually lessens approaching 2000 and going above, that's why I'll keep it in a lower gear till I get out of it.

Comment: Regarding too much initial ignition timing is this a spark plug fault?